# vue draggable items between 2 components

Tags: vuejs2

I have a component that displays a list. I have another component that also displays a list.
They sit together on another component eg:

```
<template>
<div>
  <my-component-1 :items="listItems1"/>
  <my-component-2 :items="listItems2"/>
</div>
</template>
```

Is it possible to use a library such as vue-draggable to drag items from one component to the other?

Thanks

Comment: Yes.That's possible.

Comment: ok thanks have you got a link to some example code? The only example i can find is dragging within the same component.

Comment: You can check here =>https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/tree/master/examples

Comment: anyone know of any live demos that show this functionality

Comment: This can surely help you. https://jsfiddle.net/92thunder/9kozvp8y/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.
vuedraggable support many Sortable events like move, update ...

you can get new index and old index with this events and change items with indexes in your data().

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuedraggable#events